# Ошибки репозиториев, связанные с архитектурой armhf

Tags: linux, arm, репозиторий

При некоторых действиях, появляются подобные ошибки.

**apt update && apt upgrade** выдаёт эти ошибки:
`N: Пропускается получение настроенного файла «backport/binary-armhf/Packages», так как репозиторий «http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia InRelease» не поддерживает архитектуру «armhf»` и
`E: Не удалось получить http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]`

Вход в **Диспетчер драйверов** выдал эту ошибку:
`W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'`

**lscpu** пишет, что у меня архитектура `amd64`

*Процессор Intel Celeron N4000 CPU, на ноутбуке Acer. Linux Mint Xfce 19.3.*

Это реально мешает, половина пакетов не устанавливаются. Заранее спасибо!

Примечание: вывод команды **echo print-architecture; dpkg --print-architecture; echo print-foreign-architectures; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures; head -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}**

````
amd64
print-foreign-architectures
i386
armhf
==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 19.3 _Tricia_ - Release amd64 20191213]/ bionic contrib main non-free

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/keybase.list <==
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list <==
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia main upstream import backport 

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qbittorrent-team-qbittorrent-stable-bionic.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu bionic main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scribus-ppa-bionic.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/scribus/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/scribus/ppa/ubuntu bionic main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list <==
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list <==
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list <==
deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam

# Uncomment these lines to try the beta version of the Steam launcher
#deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam
#deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list <==
###   TeamViewer DEB repository list

### NOTE: Manual changes to this file
###        - prevent it from being updated by TeamViewer package updates
###        - will be lost after using the 'teamviewer repo' command
###       The original file can be restored with this command:
###       cp /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list
###       which has the same effect as 'teamviewer repo default'

### NOTE: It is preferred to use the following commands to edit this file:
###       teamviewer repo                - show current repository configuration
###       teamviewer repo default        - restore default configuration
###       teamviewer repo disable        - disable the repository
###       teamviewer repo stable         - make all regular TeamViewer packages available (default)
###       teamviewer repo preview        - additionally, make feature preview packages available
###       teamviewer repo development    - additionally, make the latest development packages available


deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main

# deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview main
# deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb development main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list <==
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-indicator-kdeconnect-bionic.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu bionic main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-bionic.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic main```
````

Comment: приложите к вопросу (нажав [edit]) полный вывод команды: `$ echo print-architecture; dpkg --print-architecture; echo print-foreign-architectures; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures; head -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}`

Comment: Добавил. @aleksandrbarakin

Comment: ну, вот можете начать с удаления архитектуры armhf из списка «иностранных»: `$ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf`

Comment: Может быть, сработало, но вывода нет. @aleksandrbarakin

Comment: вам нужен вывод или результат — отсутствие описанных вами ошибок при выполнении описанных вами команд?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что еще не знаю, произошло ли что-либо. Сейчас проверю. @aleksandrbarakin

Comment: Работает! Спасибо, @aleksandrbarakin !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf`

> ну, вот можете начать с удаления архитектуры armhf из списка «иностранных»: $ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf – aleksandr barakin